# Add customer successfully in US version of QuickBooks Online but getting validatiuon error in Canadian version of QBO through Intuit API in PHP

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I am using QBO IPP PHP SDK QuickBooks V3 API.
The errors are

"6000: [A business validation error has occurred while processing your request, Business Validation Error: Something this action required is no longer available.  Another user may have deleted it.  Please refresh your screen to see the current information.]"

"6000: [A business validation error has occurred while processing your request, Business Validation Error: You can only add or edit one name at a time. Please try again."

But When I get Customer Detail through same API then I get successfully All the customer details.

Any one can guide me.
sorry, I forget to tell that I am using Canadian version Quick Books "https://ca.qbo.intuit.com".

Here is my Sample code for Add customer But the error is still not understandable for me.

***I am using V3 API***

$CustomerService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Customer();

```
$Customer = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Customer();
$Customer->setTitle('MR');
$Customer->setGivenName('Abdul');
$Customer->setMiddleName('Hanan');
$Customer->setFamilyName('Cheema');
$Customer->setFullyQualifiedName('FullyQualifiedName cheema');
$Customer->setDisplayName('Abdul Hanan Cheema ' . mt_rand(0, 1000));

    $Customer->setCompanyName('Seed Corporation');
    $Customer->setPrintOnCheckName('PrintOnCheckName See');
    $Customer->setActive('1');

    $Customer->setDefaultTaxCodeRef('12');
    $Customer->setTaxable('0');
    $Customer->setJob('jobSee');

    $Customer->setBillWithParent('0');
    $Customer->setBalance('100');
    $Customer->setBalanceWithJobs('0');
    $Customer->setCurrencyRef('CAD');
    $Customer->setPreferredDeliveryMethod('Email');
   // $Customer->setJob('jobSee');


// Terms (e.g. Net 30, etc.)
$Customer->setSalesTermRef(4);

// Phone #
$PrimaryPhone = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_PrimaryPhone();
$PrimaryPhone->setFreeFormNumber('860-532-0099');
$Customer->setPrimaryPhone($PrimaryPhone);

// Mobile #
$Mobile = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Mobile();
$Mobile->setFreeFormNumber('860-532-0099');
$Customer->setMobile($Mobile);

// Fax #
$Fax = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Fax();
$Fax->setFreeFormNumber('860-532-0099');
$Customer->setFax($Fax);

// Bill address
$BillAddr = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_BillAddr();
$BillAddr->setLine1('Office#2 Ali Tower');
$BillAddr->setLine2('GUlburg3');
$BillAddr->setCity('Lahore');
$BillAddr->setCountrySubDivisionCode('PK');
$BillAddr->setPostalCode('44000');
$Customer->setBillAddr($BillAddr);

// Email
$PrimaryEmailAddr = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_PrimaryEmailAddr();
$PrimaryEmailAddr->setAddress('support@consolibyte.com');
$Customer->setPrimaryEmailAddr($PrimaryEmailAddr);

if ($resp = $CustomerService->add($Context, $realm, $Customer))
{
    print('Our new customer ID is: [' . $resp . '] (name "' . $Customer->getDisplayName() . '")');
}
else
{
    print($CustomerService->lastError($Context));
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

For this error:

> "6000: [A business validation error has occurred while processing your
>   request, Business Validation Error: Something this action required is
>   no longer available. Another user may have deleted it. Please refresh
>   your screen to see the current information.]"

You need to check everything you're referring to (SalesTerm, TaxCode) and make sure those actually exist. One of them doesn't.

For this error:

> "6000: [A business validation error has occurred while processing your
>   request, Business Validation Error: You can only add or edit one name
>   at a time. Please try again."

Make sure you're only adding/editing one thing at a time.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was using Sales term refrence that is the reason of this error. Now I am using ItemRef that work accurately.

Answer (score 0):

When you do an update, you need to do a read first to get the latest metadata and synctoken for the entity. Then you should use that to do an update. Full or Sparse.
 suspect that you are not sending the Id or correct synctoken for update. Please paste your request/response xmls here.

Comment: when I add customer to the Canadian version of QuickBooks Online (https://ca.qbo.intuit.com) through the same QuickBooks API V3 and same PHP programming code, then the QuickBooks API V3 generate error mentioned above. In spite of this customer does not already exist in the QBO.
My code connection and QBO customer Class Instantiation with Canadian version of QuickBooks Online (https://ca.qbo.intuit.com) is accurate because I fetch customer data successfully from Canadian version of QuickBooks Online accurately.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest you to generate the request/response xml files for your customer create from code. Compare it with the cutomer read response you have. There is some incorrect tag you are setting for a CA customer.

Answer (score 0):

In the application layer there is a lock across Employee, Customer and Vendor entities to ensure unique name constraint. The above error comes, when you try to modify/create multiple objects using parallel threads. Please call API sequentially for the above 3 name entities. If you still face any error, you can update your post with corresponding request(and API requestID) and response XML.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

***I used ItemRef for referencing Customer instead of AnyIntuitObject reference e.g sales termrefrence, IncomeAccountRef etc.***